# Very Weird Behavior: Delphi 5 adding a component on my form with empty name

Tags: delphi, ide

Now this is a very puzzling matter I hope you can help me.

I have a custom component derived from TCustomControl that is included in a package. This package is correctly compiled and installed in D5. The package also requires the use of another library of components the ImageEn library.

I have an application that uses this component, Now until some day ago everything seemed to be fine, but now, after some recent changes to the component (mostly changing the name of the types it uses) I am having a very weird behavior going on. On the form where this component is placed Delphi will create I would say just for no reason a TImageEnIo component (from the ImageEn library) that was not even included in the dfm of the form.

Even more puzzling is the fact that this added imageenio component has no name, thus causing me a lot of trouble when I try to run the application (run-time error). If I delete this component it will reappear as soon as something is updated (for example if I switch between the text and the form of the dfm). Delphi just adds this thing on any form , where I use my custom component. This happens only when my custom component is present, other comps of the package do not generate this problem.

I noticed that it creates 1 of these empty TImageenio for each custom component I have on the form, and moreover if I switch back and forth between the text and the form views of the dfmit will add another imageenio component each time I do this.

Finally the problem is not dependent from the application as it will happen with any application as long as I add my custom component on a form.

Now I have been recompiling everything the imageen and my package many times, I have even tried to restore an older version of the component but the problem persisted (I am quite sure I hadn't experience it with the older version), I have tried anything conceivable but I cannot figure it out. I am at a complete loss, please advice If you need more info please ask, I will try to explain better.

Many Thanks to those who will take the time to answer.

Answer (score 3):

It would seem that the problem was introduced by recent changes in your custom component.

You should use your revision control system to go back to a known good version. Then advance to intermediate versions of the code, perhaps using a binary search for efficiency. Once you've isolated the revision which introduced the bug then you should be able to study the code changes in that revision and identify the problem.

Comment: +1 This is the most important reason of having a revision/version/sourcecode/ control system or configuration-management system in the first place. Btw: congrats on the 10k!

Comment: Presumably the down-vote comes from someone who doesn't believe in revision control.

Answer (score 3):

Wild guess: Your custom component directly or indirectly instantiates a TImageEnIo with the wrong Owner. Instead of using Self (i.e. the custom component instance) it uses its Owner property, which points to the form it is sitting on.

Comment: Oh my God I didn't see that!! Actually I don't know why I had a TImageenio created having as owner the owner of my custom control. Here is the guilty code: 

fBrowser_WIA_IO := TImageenio.Create(aOwner);

instead should have been 

  fBrowser_WIA_IO := TImageenio.Create(nil);

It's crazy because I never instantiate component that way, I must have been drunk that night when I wrote that.

THANK YOU, (I Was becoming mad :)

Comment: If this actually solved your problem, what about "accepting" this answer?

Comment: @Francesco - ..and an up-vote perhaps since Uwe saved you the trouble of installing the component to another IDE etc?..

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would try would be to start a new application, create one of your custom controls at run time and put breakpoints on the third party source code where the `TImageEnIo` component is instantiated, constructor of the component would be fine. If the design time behavior is exhibited at also run-time, the breakpoint would be hit and you would be able to figure out the code part creating the component from the stack trace.

Otherwise, it is possible to debug design-time behavior by debugging the IDE with another instance of the IDE, but I don't know how it can be done with D5.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. -Yes the debugging seemed like an option to me, but it seems that the ide adds the unnamed component to the dfm, so basically it is the modified dfm that tells the application to instantiate it. Another thing I have noticed is that if I give a name to the TImageenio component, then the ide automatically creates a new unnamed TImageenio again on the form. It looks like my component and this "ghost" TImageenIo are like married by some kind of black magic. What I want to try now is to install the component on delphi 2010 and see if I get the same problem there.